# Reference to a TCPListener and TcpStream from one thread to a Struct in another thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety

The current issue that I am having is creating a way to reference the TCPListener from a thread into the Struct of the main thread. The end goal of what I am trying to accomplish is a way to reference the server's TCP connections from the Server struct.

Here is the code:

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::sync::{Arc, mpsc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let server = Server::start("127.0.0.1:25565".to_string());
    loop {
        for client in server.connected_clients {
            println!("{:?}", client.stream.peer_addr().unwrap())
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Server {
    listener: Arc<Mutex<TcpListener>>,
    connected_clients: Vec<Client>,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn start(address: String) -> Server {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(address).unwrap();

        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        let listener = Arc::new(Mutex::new(listener));

        let server = Server {
            listener: listener,
            connected_clients: Vec::new()
        };

        tx.send(&server.listener).unwrap();

        thread::spawn(|| {
            let listener = rx.recv().unwrap();
            // For each new connection start a new thread
            for stream in listener.lock().unwrap().incoming() {
                let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    // TODO: Add client to the connected_clients Vec
                    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
                    loop {
                        stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
                        println!("{}", String::from_utf8(Vec::from(&buffer[..])).unwrap().trim_end_matches(char::from(0)));
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        server
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Client {
    id: usize,
    stream: TcpStream,
}
```

ERROR: std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<&Arc<Mutex>>` cannot be shared between threads safely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm uncertain where you got the idea from to use `channel` to send an object to a thread you just spawned, but it's definitely incorrect in this case.

Just use a `move ||` closure instead to move outer variables into it.

With that in mind, this code compiles: (although I have no way to test if it works)

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let server = Server::start("127.0.0.1:25565".to_string());
    loop {
        for client in &server.connected_clients {
            println!("{:?}", client.stream.peer_addr().unwrap())
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Server {
    listener: Arc<Mutex<TcpListener>>,
    connected_clients: Vec<Client>,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn start(address: String) -> Server {
        let server = Server {
            listener: Arc::new(Mutex::new(TcpListener::bind(address).unwrap())),
            connected_clients: Vec::new(),
        };

        let listener = server.listener.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            // For each new connection start a new thread
            for stream in listener.lock().unwrap().incoming() {
                let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    // TODO: Add client to the connected_clients Vec
                    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
                    loop {
                        stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
                        println!(
                            "{}",
                            String::from_utf8(Vec::from(&buffer[..]))
                                .unwrap()
                                .trim_end_matches(char::from(0))
                        );
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        server
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Client {
    id: usize,
    stream: TcpStream,
}
```

---

Technically, while being complete overkill in this case, your `channel` approach would work as well, but then you have to send an actual instance of the object instead of a reference. And you still need to use a `move ||` closure to move the `rx` object into it.

```
use std::io::Read;
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let server = Server::start("127.0.0.1:25565".to_string());
    loop {
        for client in &server.connected_clients {
            println!("{:?}", client.stream.peer_addr().unwrap())
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Server {
    listener: Arc<Mutex<TcpListener>>,
    connected_clients: Vec<Client>,
}

impl Server {
    pub fn start(address: String) -> Server {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(address).unwrap();

        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        let listener = Arc::new(Mutex::new(listener));

        let server = Server {
            listener: listener,
            connected_clients: Vec::new(),
        };

        tx.send(server.listener.clone()).unwrap();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            let listener = rx.recv().unwrap();
            // For each new connection start a new thread
            for stream in listener.lock().unwrap().incoming() {
                let mut stream = stream.unwrap();
                thread::spawn(move || {
                    // TODO: Add client to the connected_clients Vec
                    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
                    loop {
                        stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
                        println!(
                            "{}",
                            String::from_utf8(Vec::from(&buffer[..]))
                                .unwrap()
                                .trim_end_matches(char::from(0))
                        );
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        server
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Client {
    id: usize,
    stream: TcpStream,
}
```

---

One last remark:

I question the usefulness of the entire construct, though. As soon as your thread is inside the `for` loop, your `listener` is continuously locked, meaning, whoever tries to actually access it through your `Server` object will simply deadlock.